# Find polynomials $p(x) $ such that $(x+10)p(2x)=(8x-32)p(x+6) $ when $p(1)=210$

Tags: polynomials

Hi I have polynomials as below form.

$(x+10)p(2x)=(8x-32)p(x+6)$, when $p(1)=210$

I try to assign some $x$ eg. $0.5$ , $-6$ but can not find the correct relation. Any advice or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: What is your motivation for asking this question? Please see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) so that you can get a good answer.

Comment: Dear Toby Mak, Thank you very much. This is my first question in community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $S$ be the set of zeroes of $p$.

If $x \in S$, $x \ne -4$ then $$\underbrace{(x+4)}_{\ne 0}p(2x-12) = 8(x-10)p((x-6)+6) = 8(x-10)p(x) = 0$$
so $2x-12 \in S$.

Notice that $8 \in S$ since plugging in $x = 4$ gives $14p(8) = 8(4-4)p(10) = 0$.

Therefore $4 = 2\cdot 8 -12 \in S$ and then $-4 = 2\cdot 4 - 12 \in S$ so $\{8,-4,4\} \subseteq S$.

@Vasily Mitch noticed that $\deg p = 3$ so the only solution is $S = \{8,-4,4\}$ or $$p(x) = a(x-8)(x-4)(x+4)$$
for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$. From $p(1) = 210$ it follows $a = 2$.

Comment: Dear mechanodroid, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

If $p(x)=a_0x^n+\ldots+a_{n-1}x+a_n$, then considering highest order, we conclude:
$$
a_0(2x^{n})\times x = a_0x^{n}\times8x,\\
2^n = 8,\qquad n=3.
$$
So it's a polynomial of order 3: $p(x)=a_0x^3+a_1x^2+a_2x+a_3$.

Then you have  to write the expression for polynomial:
$$
(x+10)(8a_0x^3+4a_1x^2+2a_2x+a_3) = (8x+32)(a_0(x+6)^3+a_1(x+6)^2+a_2(x+6)+a_3),
$$
express every $a_i$ in terms of $a_0$, and finally use $p(1)=210$ to find the $a_0$.

Comment: Dear Vasily Mitch, Thank you.